# Unix Time Stamp starts with "1970/01/01 02:00:00" in PHP

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I see "1970/01/01 **02:00:00**" when I run that script:

```
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s',0) ;
```

Why does it start with "02:00:00"??

Comment: It doesn't, it starts with "1970"... edit your question and explain your issue more clearly

Comment: `H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros 00 through 23` -- [Date/time format documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Timezone issues...

Comment: The `date` function formats the date based on server's current time zone. You'll notice that in manual examples, people use `date_default_timezone_set` to affect how this function behaves. That's one of many reasons why using `DateTime` class is preferred over `date` and its friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your local default time zone is not the Greenwich time zone.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT");
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s',0);
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are in/have set PHP to a UTC+2 timezone. Use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to set it to UTC to see UTC time. Or use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/gmdate) instead of `date` which always outputs times in that timezone.

*(Caveat emptor that UTC is not GMT, but close enough for this example.)*

Comment: `close enough` - The motto of PHP